# Fried graphics card, how to proceed?

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card

Motherboard: Biostar TPower I45

I fried my graphics card (white smoke), by removing the cable marked PCI-E from the card, and then booting.

Removed the graphics card, and now the machine is booting, and I can ping it.
However I have no possibility to see what is actually happening, because I can't attach a monitor.

Can I workaround the lack of monitor in some way, just to see if the motherboard is fine, attach a cable and telnet in or any other way ?
Or, do I have to buy and install a new graphics card to be sure ?

Comment: machine is running ubuntu 9.10, VNC not enabled

Comment: You say you can ping it, which means to me it must be able to establish an internet connection, if the motherboard was fried I don't see how it would establish an OS much less an internet connection.

Comment: Do you have SSH or any other servers installed?  Also, hard to believe you can fry a graphics card simply by not plugging it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Biostar TPower doesn't have integrated graphics, so if you want to see what's going on you'll have to fit a new graphics card.

Answer (score 2):

Is this a Windows computer?  If it is you can see if remote desktop is enabled.  Start>Run `mstsc` and then enter the name or IP of your fried computer.  You can also get to it from the start menu.  I think under accessories, but I'm not in front of a windows machine right now to check for sure.

If it is running Linux try ssh.  From another Linux command line `ssh username@computer`